# How to convert a russian/arabic word (stored as varbinary in SQL Server) with VFP to another table in SQL Server as nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, multilingual, visual-foxpro, foxpro, varbinary

TABLES and DATATYPES

- `TablaLanguage.fieldRussian` is of datatype `varbinary(max)`
- An example of the data stored here is: 0xC3B1C3A0C3B5C3A0C3B0
- `TableString.fieldRussian` is of datatype `nvarchar(max)`
- And example stored here should be: алкоголь

THE DATA

The English translation for the example data is alcohol

CODE / THINGS I'VE TRIED

Retrieving the varbinary data without the 0x prefix I use the following cast

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), language18, 2)
FROM decl_groups 
WHERE language1 = 'suiker'
```

However if I do this same exact cast in VFP with an ODBC query I get a different result.

The ODBC query:

```
TEXT TO cSQL NOSHOW
      select CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), fieldRussian, 2) as alcohol
      from TablaLanguage
     where language1 = 'alcohol'
ENDTEXT

ODBC_Query(cSQL, "test")
```

In vfp the result then is

```
'C3A0C3ABC3AAC3AEC3A3C3AEC3ABC3BC20202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020'
```

**Question**: I've tried all kind of STRCONV() and SYS() but i don't seem to get it working.. I guess i am not even getting the right input to start to SRTCONV() to begin with as it isn't the same as i have stared in the DB.Does anyone know how to do this kind of conversion and could explain this to me, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

In the previous post you wrote, i suggested you an usefull article by Rick Strahl ([Using Unicode in Vfp](https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/foxunicode/foxunicode.asp)) in which he talks about VPF and Unicode.

Considerating you problem here it is how i solved it:

```
** Selection from Binary table **
TEXT TO cSQL NOSHOW
     select fieldRussian as alcohol
     from TablaLanguage
     where language1 = 'alcohol'
ENDTEXT

CURSORSETPROP("MapBinary",.t.,0)
ODBC_Query(cSQL, "cBinaryData")

lcBinaryString = cBinaryData.alcohol

** Insert into nVarchar table **
TEXT TO cSQL_Vc NOSHOW
     INSERT INTO TableString(fieldRussian) VALUES (CAST(?lcBinaryString as nVarchar(MAX)))
ENDTEXT

ODBC_Query(cSQL_Vc, "cData")
```

Setting cursor's property MapBinary, to .T. i'm mapping SQL Varbinary to VPF blob type.

As he says, unfortunately, Vpf doesn't support Unicode natively and so if you would display somenthing in UNICODE inside a VPF form you should use some ActiveX control.

Comment: I tried the way you gave to solve the problem. Unfortuanatly it didn't work for me. The result was some chinese looking charachters, when it should be arrabic or russian. 
So as suggested i used an OLE textbox and soms SYS() methodes for changeing the COM page,  which at the end gave me the result i wanted. 
What i don't understand is what exactly do these ActiveX controls which makes it possible to display the text as wanted?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of searching this is how i made it work. Seems like it isn't possible to store an varbinary field to another table as nvarchar with only SQL.  So foxpro en the use of an activeX Control was required. 
A real explenation why it works this way i can not give, but if someone could help me understand its always wewlcome.

IF !EMPTY(cexport_ingred_decl.declaratie_blob) 
&& field that's stored in db as varbinary and needs to be stored in another table as nvarchar
      TEXT TO cSQL NOSHOW
         SELECT codepage as codepagina
         FROM codepages
         WHERE language = ?ccur_talen.taalnummer
      ENDTEXT
      ODBC_Query(cSQL, 'ccur_codepages')

```
 SYS(3101, ccur_codepages.codepagina)                                                      
 oform.addobject("oletextbox1","recoletextbox")                                   
 test = STRCONV(cexport_ingred_decl.declaratie_blob,9)                      
 oform.oletextbox1.text = STRCONV(test,11)                                          

 SYS(3101,0)                                                                                               
 USE IN ccur_codepages  

 SYS(987,.F.)                                               

 SYS(3101,65001)                                                                                                 
 *** Convert UTF-8 to Unicode and store as BINARY string!!!
 pcSavedDescription =  STRCONV(oform.oletextbox1.text,12)                      

pcSavedDescription = CREATEBINARY(pcSavedDescription)                       
oform.removeobject("oletextbox1")
```

ENDIF

INSERT IN DB AS follow:
 INSERT INTO tablename (field )
 VALUES(CAST(?pcSavedDescription as nvarchar(max)))